# SIM7000E - HTTPS connection with AT+SHCONN failing with "CME ERROR: operation not allowed"

Tags: http, ssl, https, at-command

I'm trying to connect with SIM7000E module (I'm using waveshare SIM7000E NB-IoT HAT board) using HTTPS to https://httpbin.org, however whatever I try, I get an error after using command AT+SHCONN with a message "CME ERROR: operation not allowed".
When I try to connect with HTTP to http://httpbin.org using the same code, everything works fine and AT+SHCONN command returns "OK".
I'm out of ideas what I could be doing wrong, has anyone solved this issue? Below I paste AT commands I use to connect to https://httpbin.org:

AT 
 OK

AT+CMEE=2 
 OK`

AT+CPIN? 
 CPIN: READY 
 OK

AT+CGMM 
 SIMCOM_SIM7000E 
 OK

AT+CGMR 
 Revision:1351B08SIM7000E 
 OK

AT+COPS? 
 COPS: 0,0,"Orange Orange",3 
 OK

AT+CSQ 
 CSQ: 20,0 
 OK

AT+CNACT=1, "iot" 
 OK 
 APP PDP: ACTIVE

AT+CNACT? 
 CNACT: 1,"xxx.xx.xxx.xxx" //Here I get valid IP 
 OK

AT+CSSLCFG="ignorertctime",1,1 
 OK

AT+CSSLCFG="sslversion",1,3 
 OK

AT+SHSSL=1,"" 
 OK

AT+SHCONF="URL","https://httpbin.org" 
 OK

AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024 
 OK

AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350 
 OK

AT+SHSSL? 
 SHSSL: 1,"","" 
 OK

AT+SHCONN 
 CME ERROR: operation not allowed

I'd be grateful for any help.
I have set ignoring time with `AT+CSSLCFG="ignorertctime",1,1` and set skipping certificate verification with `AT+SHSSL=1,""`.

I have tried setting current time instead of using "AT+CSSLCFG="ignorertctime",1,1", but it fails as well. Also I tried following https://gist.github.com/baconcheese113/1f0264727fce3fa51a5bb06fa031aed2 instruction but it fails the same way with AT+SHCONN.
I have tried using different sim card and also different SIM7000E module, the same error with AT+SHCONN happens then as well.
I have also tried connecting to different URLs than "https://httpbin.org" but it is the same error with all URLs I try.

Comment: How is old is this module you use? A lot if web sites only accept TLS1.2 and 1.3 connections. 1.3 is pretty new (2018) and TLS 1.2 is way older (2008) but is was ignored by most manufacturer for years. So check if at least TLS 1.2 is supported and what TLS versions the web site supports e.g using this site https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: @Robert Well I bought it recently, few weeks ago. However I will try to update firmware, maybe it will help. I have tried now to use AT+CSSLCFG="sslversion",1,2 instead of 1,3, but it still failed the same way

Comment: I just saw that `https://httpbin.org` still supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, so the supported TLS versions should not be the problem. I would first try to connect to an own server where you can sniff traffic using Wireshark/tshark to see what data is transmitted and see the TLS handshake sent.